# Can I say 'I said it second'?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

Like how you can say: 

'I said it first' to mean that you said something first. 


Can you also say:

'I said it second' to mean that you said something second? and would it sound natural?


I apologise in advance if this question sounds ridiculous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dictionaries do offer definitions of *second* as an adverb, but the meaning is usually different than the one you're looking for, for instance:

> 1 : in the second place : *secondly* 
> //These two kinds of image … have a powerful appeal for us, first, because we are all … inevitably concerned about our fate, and second, because our concern is itself twofold…
>
> 2 : before all others with one exception
> //the nation's second largest city
>  //They are my second favorite band.
>
> https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/second

or

> 21. in the second place, rank, group, etc.
>
> https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/second

(as in, "she finished second")

That said, sentences like "I said it second" are very common. The fact that I can't find this meaning in any dictionary seems to confirm my suspicion that this is an informal use of *second*.

In other words, it's natural, but I probably wouldn't use it when writing a paper.